# Delete last screenshot taken in iOS =>9 without user authorisation?

Tags: ios, screenshot, phphotolibrary

I've requirement to disable taking screenshot in iOS device. since Apple not giving support for that, another workaround Im trying is - get notified when screenshot is taken using `UIApplicationUserDidTakeScreenshotNotification` and get last photo from photo gallery and delete it as below code -

```
func deleteLastTakenScreenshotFromLibrary() {
    let fetchOptions: PHFetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
    fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)]
    let fetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .image, options: fetchOptions)

    if (fetchResult.firstObject != nil) {
        var firstAsset: PHAsset = fetchResult.firstObject as! PHAsset
        let arrayToDelete = NSArray(object: firstAsset)
        PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges( {
            PHAssetChangeRequest.deleteAssets(arrayToDelete)},
                                                            completionHandler: {
                                                                success, error in
                                                                print("Finished deleting asset. %@", (success ? "Success" : error))
        })
    }
```

But here I found 2 problems -

a).app is asking user permission like `Allow <App Name> to delete this photo? This photo will be deleted from iCloud Photo Library on all your devices.`

b).after clicking `allow`, app is not deleting that last photo permanently.

Even I added below permissions in `info.plist`

1).`Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description`

2).`Privacy - Media Library Usage Description`

I don't know how I can fulfil this requirement. Please help, your help is much appreciated. Thanks. :)

Comment: Apple won't let you delete things from the user's photo library without their permission. Preventing screenshots is, essentially, pointless since even if you could, the user could simply photograph their screen if they really want to capture the screen

Comment: When you delete an image from an app, first a dialog comes up asking the user if they want to delete it and then it sticks the shot in the recently deleted folder. You can't get around these.

Comment: Is it possible to delete the image from the recently deleted folder as well?

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of `PHPhotoLibrary`:

> For each call to the performChanges(*:completionHandler:) or performChangesAndWait(*:) method, Photos shows an alert asking the user for permission to edit the contents of the photo library.

Comment: Hi Gereon.. can u suggest any work around for this ?

Comment: No. As far as I can tell, your requirement cannot be implemented.

Comment: Okay.. can we hide view contents when home button is pressed?

Comment: Yes, in `applicationDidEnterBackground`.

Comment: I used `applicationDidEnterBackground` event in appdelegate, it works only when user press home or lock button but for home + lock (for screen shot), its not working.. any suggestions Gereon?

Comment: No, like I said: your requirement cannot be implemented.